# Listing files in a directory into navigation - need to add class to first

Tags: php, list, file, directory, navigation

I've been using the following to output navigation from a specific directory but need to adjust it slightly. How can I add `class="first"` to the first `<li>` item that is outputted? For the life of me I can't seem to work out how!

```
<?php
function navigation($path) {
    if ($handle = opendir($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$path)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != 'index.php') {
                $label = str_replace('.php', '', $file);
                $label = str_replace("-", " ", $label);
                $label = ucfirst($label);
                $file = str_replace('.php', '/', $file);
                $links[] = '<li><a href="' . $path . $file . '" title="' . $label . '">' . $label . '</a></li>' . "\n";
                sort($links);
            }
        }
        foreach($links as $link) {
            echo ($link);
        }

        closedir($handle);
    }
}
?>
```

I then call `<?php navigation("/directory-name/"); ?>` where I want it to appear in the page.

This currently would output something like:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="Path to file" title="Label">Label</a></li>
    <li><a href="Path to file" title="Label">Label</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand, but I can give you what I guessed.

First, initiate this variable *outside* of the while loop.

```
$first = true;
```

Then, at the ***very end*** of the while loop, do this:

```
$first = false;
```

Before you set that to false, just use this for finding if the item is the first:

```
$class = $first?" class='first'":'';
```

And put the `$class` variable inside the `li` tag the output string.

Comment: Thanks very much. Sorted the problem. The first item of the navigation needed the class first to style it slightly different from the rest. Thanks for your time.

Comment: No problem. It didn't take five minutes to write :)

Answer (score 1):

**Using a variable**

The first time the loop will be repeated the variable `$first_time` equals to true. You can then use that variable in an if statement to determine the class of the current `li` element.

**Edit your code to this**

```
<?php
function navigation($path) {
    $first_item = true;

    if ($handle = opendir($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$path)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != 'index.php') {
                if($first_item === true)    $li_class = ' class="first"';
                else                        $li_class = '';

                $label = str_replace('.php', '', $file);
                $label = str_replace("-", " ", $label);
                $label = ucfirst($label);
                $file = str_replace('.php', '/', $file);
                $links[] = '<li' . $li_class . '><a href="' . $path . $file . '" title="' . $label . '">' . $label . '</a></li>' . "\n";
                sort($links);

                $first_item = false;
            }
        }
        foreach($links as $link) {
            echo ($link);
        }

        closedir($handle);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't seem to have worked. No errors but it's not outputting any different.

Comment: @Marc Sanders: I am sorry, I have made a mistake. I have tested and updated my question. I have moved `$first_item = false`. It is working for me now.

Answer (score 0):

I would take the `<li>` tags out of the first round of link creation, so that the line that creates the link would just be

```
$links[] = '<a href="' . $path . $file . '" title="' . $label . '">' . $label . '</a>';
```

And then add them in the final iteration (since that's after your sort)

```
    foreach($links as $key=>$link) {
        class="";
        if ($key==0) class = " class='first'";
        echo ('<li'.class.'>'.$link.'</li>\n');
    }
```

Comment: This is also seems a good solution so will try this example out too. Thanks for your time.